# Why Explanation of score is not the best score?

Tags: optaplanner

I am doing a planning program using optaplanner 7.12, but found that sometimes, the explanation of score is not the same as best score, below is an example, pls help to tell me why? Thank you optaplanner Team!

```
  Solving ended: 
    time spent (900000), 
    best score (0hard/-1764medium/0soft), 
    score calculation speed (381/sec), 
    phase total (1), 
    environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE).

Explanation of score (-1000hard/-1764medium/-200soft):
    Constraint match totals:
        -1000hard: constraint (task ETD not in holiday) has 1 matches:
            -1000hard: justifications ([Task [Task_name=1-PKGK19VE0006414A-EGV-2019-08-31/2019-08-01/SEA-3-N, extract_ct=3, waitting_time=84, searchRange=85, searchRangeDown=54]])
        -1319medium: constraint (Loading not over ots_ratio) has 10 matches:
            -390medium: justifications ([染色 12 taskList: [] ots_ratio:-390 ttl_ots_ratio:0])
            -190medium: justifications ([染色 19 taskList: [] ots_ratio:-190 ttl_ots_ratio:0])
            ...
        -445medium: constraint (Gmt_Loading not over overcapacity_ratio) has 22 matches:
            -57medium: justifications ([EAV 19-W22-(5&6) taskList: [] overcapacity_ratio:-58])
            -51medium: justifications ([EAV 19-W30-7 taskList: [] overcapacity_ratio:-52])
            ...
        -200soft: constraint (task ETD should equals old_delivery_date) has 1 matches:
            -200soft: justifications ([Task [Task_name=1-PKGK19VE0006414A-EGV-2019-08-31/2019-08-01/SEA-3-N, extract_ct=3, waitting_time=84, searchRange=85, searchRangeDown=54]])
    Indictments (top 5 of 33):
        -1000hard/-200soft: justification (Task [Task_name=1-PKGK19VE0006414A-EGV-2019-08-31/2019-08-01/SEA-3-N, extract_ct=3, waitting_time=84, searchRange=85, searchRangeDown=54]) has 2 matches:
            -1000hard: constraint (task ETD not in holiday)
            -200soft: constraint (task ETD should equals old_delivery_date)
        -390medium: justification (染色 12 taskList: [] ots_ratio:-390 ttl_ots_ratio:0) has 1 matches:
            -390medium: constraint (Loading not over ots_ratio)
        -190medium: justification (染色 19 taskList: [] ots_ratio:-190 ttl_ots_ratio:0) has 1 matches:
            -190medium: constraint (Loading not over ots_ratio)
        -164medium: justification (抓毛 12 taskList: [] ots_ratio:-164 ttl_ots_ratio:0) has 1 matches:
            -164medium: constraint (Loading not over ots_ratio)
        -127medium: justification (染色 5 taskList: [] ots_ratio:-127 ttl_ots_ratio:0) has 1 matches:
            -127medium: constraint (Loading not over ots_ratio)
        ...
```

below is one of the drools Hard Constraint:

```
rule "task ETD not in holiday"
   salience 300
    when 
        $Task:Task(!plan_flag.equals("1.MPS计算-N"),$Task_name:Task_name,$ETD:JS_ETD_Calendar_ETD_drools(waitting_time,extract_ct,destination,Delivery_Method),$check_holiday:check_holiday(JS_ETD_Calendar_ETD_drools(waitting_time,extract_ct,destination,Delivery_Method)));
        eval($check_holiday>0)//eval($check_holiday>0)

    then

    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1000); 
    end

below in main class,I use solver.explainBestScore():
    System.out.println(solver.explainBestScore());
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `<environmentMode>FULL_ASSERT</>`. You're probably suffering from score corruption and that will then you exactly when it happens.